# Accessing xrdp via Windows 10 RDP Reboots Pi

Tags: raspbian-stretch, rdp, xrdp

I'm suddenly running into a problem accessing a Raspberry Pi 3B+ on my LAN from my Windows 10 desktop using Remote Desktop. Up until about a week ago everything had been running fine for well over a year. The Pi is running stretch and has all the latest updates installed via apt-get.

Now when I try to connect from within Windows the Pi generally crashes and reboots.

I'm unclear as to how to go about diagnosing this situation. Suggestions along those lines, as well as ideas as to what the problem may be, would be appreciated.

**Additional Info**

In exploring the logs I noticed that dnsmasq was complaining about being asked to apply a second IP address to a host that already had one. Researching that I discovered, via ifconfig, that the Pi's wireless interface -- which I thought I had disabled long ago -- was running, and had been assigned an address via dnsmasq.

Disabling the wifi interface by modifying /boot/config.txt eliminated that problem, and >>may<< have eliminated the xrdp crashing problem. So far I've been able to access xrdp from within Windows RDP multiple times without crashing the Pi. Fingers crossed :).

Comment: What error messages associated to the crash do you find with `journalctl -b  -e`?

Comment: None. The system crashes when I try to access it from within Windows 10 via Microsoft's RDP but there are no messages in the logs, of any kind. Nor does anything show up related to the crash from journalctl.

Comment: If you have found the solution you should make an answer to finish the question.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, @Ingo. I'm a long-time stackoverflow user and know the drill. But as I indicated in my additional info I'm still testing/evaluating the change I made.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the wifi interface resolved the problem (well, at least it hasn't come back in a number of days :)).